# What is the correct way to connect a power supply to an Arduino and LED strip?

Tags: arduino, ws2812b

I am working on a project with a 5 V 15 A power supply with a barrel connector.

What is the proper (safe) way to connect this to an Arduino and also power a WS2812b strip?

I can't power the LEDs through the Arduino, so somehow I've got to split the power and go to both (then likely split the LED power to connect at the end of strip also.)

What gauge wire should I be using for this? My plan is to make an LED wall clock, so I want it to be safe to be plugged in long term.

Comment: 15A is a lot for a barrel jack. Got a link to the power supply?

Comment: Bought it a year ago, pribably over estimated power consumption since i didnt know how many leds i was gonna use. Also probably wrongly assumed i needed to account for the full 60ma on every led. 5V 15A 75W Power Supply 100V-240V or 110V - 220V AC to DC Adapter 5V 15 amp Switching Converter 5.5x2.1mm Plug for WS2811 WS2812B WS2813 2801 LED Strip Pixel Lights https://a.co/d/hqtAFw4

Comment: You need to connect them in parallel if both take 5 V input. 15 A would take about 2 mm^2 in order to not heat up more than just noticeably.  But as pointed out by @user1850479, the barrel jack is the elephant in the room here.

Comment: How many amps were you expecting to get from that supply? You could cut off the wire and solder/splice in a more appropriate one for 15A, but since this is Amazon junk it's probably not actually a 15A supply.

Comment: In reality, since my final form of the project is using 140 leds, I should probably get a lower amp supply. 140leds x 60ma x 50%=4.2 amps so I should probably downgrade to a 5amp supply, no?

Comment: Need to know the length of the wire. I would target 0.3V drop round trip at max current. You can find wire resistance tables on the web.

Comment: Very short less than 2 ft, the arduino will be mounted to the back of an array of leds.

Comment: Amazon reviews mention getting 5A without the barrel jack, so you could use that. Since you mention safety and using this in your home, rather than try to fix it's shortcomings I'd take advantage of Amazon's return policies and buy a name brand supply that I knew would meet it's specs and be up to code. Digikey wants less than you paid for that supply for name brand 5V/5A supplies.

Comment: Fair point, can't return it as I bought it last year when I was planning this. But I guess you're right about trusting a name brand.

Comment: What would be a good brand name for power supplies?

Comment: @Blueman101 Product recommendations are off-topic here, but, as mentioned previously, reputable suppliers such as Digikey, RS, Mouser, Farnell, and others, will only sell good items. With PC power supplies being a popular search topic on Google, some effort is needed to construct a search such as "reputable electronic psu brands -pc", which might lead you to brand names like Mean Well, TDK Lambda, Vicor, Delta Electronics, and Murata.